# Charts: stripline and curve intersection points

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I've added a horizontal stripline to a sinusoidal type graph which doesn't have many datapoints. Is there  a way to find the x-coordinate intersections?

Comment: Please show waht you have tried

Comment: Please provide us with infor about which library your're using and what framework the application is developed in (WPF, WF, UWP, ...).

Comment: I use  System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting  and I haven't tried anything yet except finding the nearest datapoints in my source array  fior the curve but the accuracy won't be as good as the actual intersection points

Comment: This is a non-trivial task. If you want to you can offload the hard stuff to GrahicsPath but even there it is not directly supported. Maybe your task should be tackled by math. Intersecting a sinus and a line is trivial there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either tackle it analytically, i.e. if your data are derived from a formula you can use math to solve the intersection set.

Or you can us an approximation with a little help from `GDI+`.

As you have found using the `DataPoints` directly in a thinly populated set of points  will not work well.

But there is an interesting and simple workaround that can create an enlarged set of points for you.

For this you need to use a **flattened** `GraphicsPath`:

Let's assume your values are in a `List<PointF> points`:

```
List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) points.Add(new PointF(i, (float)Math.Sin(i)));
```

Now you first create a `GraphicsPath` from it:

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
.. 
..
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddCurve(points.ToArray());
```

Then you flatten it:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();    // identity
gp.Flatten(m, yourFlatness);
```

This changes the `GraphicsPath` from a **series of curves**, (which are identical to the `Chart`'s spline curves, btw,) to a **series of line segments**. The 'flatness' determines how much the lines may deviate from the curve. so, the smaller the flatness you use (default is 0.25f), the more segments you get.

We have started with 10 `DataPoints` shown below in red. After flattening with `0.1f`, `0.01f` and `0.001f` we get `19`, `55` and `152` points/line segments respectively..:

[image]

You can acces them in the `gp.PathPoints` array and will get much closer to the real intersections. Add a little **interpolation** and you should be close enough for jazz..