# How to compute PathGeometry.GetPointAtFractionLength or equivalent in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, geometry-surface

A simple graph composed of circles and horizontal and vertical lines that responds to mouse clicks has been implemented in WPF.  But the application must be converted to Winforms, no choice in the matter.

GraphicsPath is generally just right for my needs: reasonably simple, it can find hittest points.  But to use it, I need to know the equivalent -- or how to calculate -- what WPF's PathGeometry.GetPointAtFractionLength does.  (The documentation is too scanty, and I can find no other help on how to do it.)

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent. GP has its points in the PathPoints collection (along with a type collection). So you will have to write your own method(s). See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786327/charts-stripline-and-curve-intersection-points/37788310?s=1|0.2265#37788310) on a possible and rather simple  course of action..!