# Winform chart control : how to HitTest X position of mouse cursor?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I'd need to HitTest the X position of the mouse cursor to display an annotation where the blue line that tracks the cursor position encounters the different data series I might have displayed in my chart control but I'm sure how to best achieve this. HitTesting all points of the blue vertical line seems inefficient and the HitTest method does not provide an overload requiring only the X or Y coordinate. Any smart solution to this need?

[image]

Comment: Please explain: What exactly do you need the hittest for? Without the y one can't know where you are ie what you hit..

Comment: As said, in my application mouse cursor defines/provides the horizontal position (the X value) and I'd like to display the Y value(s) for any of the intersected series. I'd like to display in the point of intersection an annotation with the Y value. So ideally I'd need a HitTest method where I provide the X coordinate and the method returns all points of intersection of any displayed series. Hope I've clarified my intent.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786327/charts-stripline-and-curve-intersection-points/37788310#37788310) is a discussion of how to find series - line intersections.